# Return rows which contain times greater than one hour

Tags: mysql, database, heidisql

I have this query:

```
SELECT s.* FROM  stop s 
WHERE 
s.hour>
        (SELECT st.hours FROM stop st
             JOIN City cit ON cit.id = st.idCity
             WHERE cit.name = 'LA' )
```

But the subquery returns more than one row, how should I proceed?

**City**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LA |
| 2 | Ny |
| 3 | AZ |

**Stop**

| id | Hour | idCity | idCityB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7:00 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 8.00 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 9:00 | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 10:00 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 11:00 | 3 | 2 |

I want 8:00, 9:00 and 11:00

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: share schema for table and sample data. Also, share the expected output from sample data.

Comment: You should use correlated subquery. I.e. you must add a condition to the subquery which selects the data for definite group defined by some value of the currectly processed outer row (from `stop AS s` table copy). And the value returned by the subquery must be aggregated one (for example, `MAX(st.hours)`).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I posted the table

Comment: @Akina with max, it doesn't return all the value

Comment: @gianluca23 what is `fer.localita` you haven't included fer table ?

Comment: *with max, it doesn't return all the value* Have you added correlation condition into the subquery?

Comment: @ErgestBasha sorry, my mistake. I changed it

Comment: @Akina I think so, what do you mean when you say: " synchronize all columns names in the query and in data sample"?

Comment: @gianluca23 I can't understand the logic, maybe is this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13e6de0f4b36c804546a2a6e167a7856 what you are trying ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha It isn't 'not in' because the query is for the bus stops if I have a bus stop before the main bus stop, the query must not take it. Sorry  for the omission it was not done on purpose

Comment: @Akina ok,I changed it

Comment: @Akina  now is all sync.  Sorry, it's my first question and I'm not english

Answer (score 0):

Possible realizations (use those which matches needed logic if present):

```sql
SELECT s.* 
FROM stop s
JOIN stop st USING (`hour`)
JOIN city cit ON cit.id = st.idcity
WHERE cit.name <> 'LA'
```

```sql
SELECT s.* 
FROM  stop s 
WHERE hour NOT IN ( SELECT st.`hour` 
                    FROM stop st 
                    JOIN city cit ON cit.id = st.idcity
                    WHERE cit.name = 'LA' )
```

On your sample data both queries gives the same desired output, but their logic differs and they will give different output on another data.